# Queue functionality issue in a simple program

Tags: jquery, queue, jquery-queue

I am trying to queue some of the changes by jQuery using the `.queue()` functionality. I can see the 'background yellow' and 'border turning orange' but I dont see shifting of the paragraph! Kindly help why its not moving leftwise by 250px! (I've added "position:relative" for "paragraph" as per the comments)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#but1').click(function() {
                    $('p').queue(function() {
                        $(this).css('background','yellow');
                        $(this).css('border', '3px solid orange');
                        $(this).animate({ left: '250px' });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id=but1>Click Me! </button> 
        <p id=para1 style="position:relative;">This is a paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Later on, I tried this script; still doesn't work, and now I cannot see even earlier 2 changes in paragraph, viz., "background:yellow" and "border:orange".

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#but1').click(function(){
    $('p')
    .queue('alpha',function(){
        $(this).css('background','yellow');
    })
    .queue('alpha',function(){
        $(this).css('border','3px solid orange');
    })
    .queue('alpha',function(){
        $(this).animate({left:'250px'},1500});
    })
    .dequeue('alpha');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: `left: 250px;` .. should be `left: '250px'`

Comment: Have you read [docs](https://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback) about this usage of `.queue()`?

Comment: Yes, regent; A better running example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#but1').click(function() {
                $('p').queue(function() {
                    $(this).css('background','yellow');
                    $(this).css('border', '3px solid orange');
                    $(this).animate({ left: '250px;' });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<body>
    <button id=but1>Click Me! </button> 
    <p id=para1>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I have removed the html and head tags, obviously you will add them. Cheers! :)

Comment: @Peterson, for me when I post this above code in JSfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) and run it, it works!

I suspect you might have some issues with your attached cs file, or you may try step by step solution posted above by M. Doye.

Comment: can you send me link ?

Answer (score 0):

To make your current code work, you simply need to specify a default `left` value and a `position`, like this:

```
#para1 {
    position:relative;
    left: 0px;
}
```

And then change the way you are using `queue`:

```
$('#but1').click(function() {  
    $(this).next('p').animate({left:'250px'},
       {queue:true, duration:600, easing: 'swing'})
    .css({'background':'yellow','border':'3px solid orange'});
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LqpsLjb/1/)

- Docs on [`animate`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)
- Docs on [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) (Will help understand why your current code is faulty)

---

Or you can *optionally* do it this way, using `addClass` and then using some CSS:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#but1').click(function() {
   $('p').queue(function() {
       $(this).css({'background':'yellow','border':'3px solid orange' });
       $(this).addClass("left");
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.left {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 250px;
    transition: margin-left .8s;
}
```

[**Another example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vff2acx6/2/)